# Story about princess, prince and dragon running away from kingdom, comedy

Tags: story-identification

Comedy story starts with a prince living under the shadow of his older brother, the crown prince, who is portrayed as a dumb jock

the prince ran away to save the princess from a dragon

> princess wasnt kidnapped by dragon, the dragon is friendly, the 3 of them ran away for some reason

theres a old frail merlin character who drank a potion and became beefy, commenting something along the lines that he isnt much of a magician if he cant modify his own body

> dumb jock crown prince turns out to be an ally, is really clever, pretending to be dumb to protect himself and his younger brother

tried googling for the story online but the keywords "dragon", "prince", "princess", "merlin" are way too common as plot elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely Simon Green's [*Blue Moon Rising*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Moon_Rising_(novel)).

The Wikipedia summary:

> Rupert's quest is to slay a dragon, proving his worth to the kingdom; however Rupert knows he has been sent to die. He stubbornly refuses to run away and proceeds with the undertaking. Rupert seeks out the notorious Night Witch who, upon finding out he is the grandson of her long dead lover provides him with a map to find a dragon. To get to his destination Rupert must pass through the Darkwood, an area in the forest where no light ever penetrates, where nothing lives except demons. Passing through the endless night Rupert is attacked by countless demons which appear to be hunting in packs though demons have never hunted in packs before.
>
> After reaching the other side of the Darkwood Rupert discovers a dragon in a cave at the top of a mountain and upon challenging him is surprised to find that not only does the dragon not have any interest in killing him, it collects butterflies. Also in the cave is Princess Julia, a seventh daughter from the Hillsdown province who was sent to the dragon as a sacrifice but which the dragon does "not have the heart" to kill.

Upon their return, Rupert is sent to find the High Warlock.  At some point, the Warlock takes a potion that turns him into his younger self.

Rupert's brother is different from Rupert's impression of him.  He is not exactly an ally, but does end up fighting the demon antagonists with Julia, each using one of three very powerful swords they recover.

I found the beginning to be very comedic with Rupert constantly complaining about how the minstrels lie about quests and glory.  The rest is...dark comedy at best.

Comment: yes, that sounds right

Comment: @istaris-j Glad that was it.  Luckily, if you like it, there are 5 total books in the series and 6 in the related Hawk & Fisher series (though they are shorter--better to get the 2 large omnibus books to get all 6).